# Error :"the command '/bin/sh -c source protected-env/bin/activate' returned a non-zero code: 127" while I'm trying to configure my first dockerfile

Tags: command-line, bash, python, docker

I'm trying to learn docker. This is my first experiment. I have written this dockerfile :

```
FROM nvidia/cudagl:11.3.0-base-ubuntu20.04

LABEL Author="ZioMario"
LABEL Title="Firefox/Docker20.10.6/Ubuntu20.04"

# Enviorment variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV PATH "$PATH:/bin/2.82/python/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
ENV FIREFOX_PATH "/bin/2.82"
ENV FIREFOXPIP "/bin/2.82/python/bin/pip3"
ENV FIREFOXPY "/bin/2.82/python/bin/python3.7m"
ENV HW="GPU"

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    apt-utils \
    wget \ 
    libopenexr-dev \ 
    bzip2 \ 
    build-essential \ 
    zlib1g-dev \ 
    libxmu-dev \ 
    libxi-dev \ 
    libxxf86vm-dev \ 
    libfontconfig1 \ 
    libxrender1 \ 
    libgl1-mesa-glx \ 
    xz-utils \
    firefox \
    openjdk-8-jre

# Download the Python source

RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tgz \ 
    && tar -xzf Python-3.7.0.tgz \ 
    && cp -r Python-3.7.0/Include/* $FIREFOX_PATH/python/include/python3.7m/ \ 
    && rm -rf Python-3.7.0.tgz \ 
    && rm -rf Python-3.7.0 

# Installing a modern version of numpy

RUN rm -rf ${FIREFOX_PATH}/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy 

# Must first ensurepip to install Firefox pip3 and then new numpy

RUN ${FIREFOXPY} -m venv protected-env

RUN source protected-env/bin/activate

RUN ${FIREFOXPY} -m ensurepip && ${FIREFOXPIP} install --upgrade pip && ${FIREFOXPIP} install numpy
RUN deactivate
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /
```

Unfortunately it does not work. This is the error that I'm getting :

**The command '/bin/sh -c source protected-env/bin/activate' returned a non-zero code: 127**

the wrong line is this :

**RUN source protected-env/bin/activate**

Do you have any idea about how to fix it ? thanks.

Comment: You tagged this `bash`, however as you can see from the error message, docker `RUN` is using `/bin/sh` - which does not recognize the `source` command

Comment: which command replace source ?

Comment: The POSIX command to source `file` is `. file` - however, I doubt that will achieve what you want here since it appears that `RUN` executes each instruction in its own shell (I don't know anything about docker though - ymmv)

Comment: you are right. I tried with . but it hasn't activated the protected environment and it didn't deactivated,also,giving this error : /bin/sh: 1: deactivate: not found. So,there is no solution here ?

Comment: You could try chaining all the venv commands together into a single `RUN` with `&&` like you have done with the pip command(s) - but like I said, I don't really know about docker